# PHP Mysql merge values (remove duplicate emails but keep values)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql with emails. Most emails are duplicates, but each one of the duplicate emails, contain different values in the `col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_4`. I want merge them (remove duplicates) and to keep the values. As final result should be like the 2nd table.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------++-------++-------++-------+
| email                                               | col_1 || col_2 || col_3 || col_4 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------++-------++-------++-------+
| a@a.com                                             |     1 ||     0 ||     0 ||     0 |
| b@b.com                                             |     0 ||     0 ||     1 ||     0 |
| a@a.com                                             |     0 ||     1 ||     0 ||     0 |
| d@d.com                                             |     1 ||     0 ||     0 ||     0 |
| a@a.com                                             |     0 ||     0 ||     0 ||     1 |
| b@b.com                                             |     0 ||     1 ||     0 ||     0 |
| d@d.com                                             |     0 ||     0 ||     0 ||     1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------++-------++-------++-------+
```

I need to merge the email column but to keep the `col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_4` values

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------++-------++-------++-------+
| email                                               | col_1 || col_2 || col_3 || col_4 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------++-------++-------++-------+
| a@a.com                                             |     1 ||     1 ||     0 ||     1 |
| b@b.com                                             |     0 ||     1 ||     1 ||     0 |
| d@d.com                                             |     1 ||     0 ||     0 ||     1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------++-------++-------++-------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to do this would be to create another table and insert into it the values you really want.  Then, delete the original table and rename the new one:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTableNew (email varchar(255), col_1 int, col_2 int, col_3 int, col_4 int)
INSERT INTO yourTableNew (email, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4)
SELECT
    email,
    SUM(col_1),
    SUM(col_2),
    SUM(col_3),
    SUM(col_4)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY email;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yourTable;
RENAME TABLE yourTableNew TO yourTable;
```

Comment: Alternative for `SUM` can be to use `MAX` if he wants to keep only 0 and 1

Comment: @Jeffrey Yeah I was also wondering about that.  For the data given, both `SUM` and `MAX` would yield the same result.  I'll let the OP comment if it has the same concern as we do.

Comment: @Jeffrey `SUM` and `MAX` will output the same result if the data will be in this format, but perhaps it really is "more" correct to use `MAX`

Comment: @sagi for the currently given example: true. But if more rows exist with overlapping ones in the same column with the same email, not true. Thus the comment.